# How should a two nic gateway be routed (FreeBSD 10.2)?

Tags: networking, freebsd, routing

I am trying to set up a freebsd router that sits between the cable/dsl modem and my lan machines. Here is the logical setup:

Cable/DSL modem connected to internet:

```
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

FreeBSD Router (with two nics):

```
em0 192.168.0.121
ue0 10.0.0.1
```

FreeBSD Lan Machine:

```
em0 10.0.0.2
```

It seems like the path from the lan to the wan should be 10.0.0.2->10.0.0.1->192.168.0.1->wan and that I should be able to ping a machine on the internet from the lan machine.

In summary, though:

- The internet is accessible from the FreeBSD router.
- The lan machine is acccessible from the FreeBSD router.
- The FreeBSD router is accessible from the lan machine.
- The internet is not accessible from the lan machine.

Here are the /etc/rc.conf entries on the router:

```
ifconfig_ue0="inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0"
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.0.121 netmask 255.255.255.0"
gateway_enable="YES"                                                   
defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"
```

Here are the /etc/rc.conf entries on the lan machine:

```
ifconfig_em0="inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="10.0.0.1"
```

Here are the routing table entries from the FreeBSD router (loki):

```
netstat -r            
Routing tables

Internet:                                          
Destination        Gateway            Flags      Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGS         em0 
10.0.0.0/24        link#3             U           ue0
10.0.0.1           link#3             UHS         lo0
127.0.0.1          link#2             UH          lo0
192.168.0.0/24     link#1             U           em0
192.168.0.121      link#1             UHS         lo0
```

Here are the routing table entries from the lan machine (freebird):

```
netstat -r
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags      Netif Expire
default            10.0.0.1           UGS         em0
10.0.0.0           link#1             U           em0
10.0.0.2           link#1             UHS         lo0
freebird           link#2             UH          lo0
```

netstat on the lan machine is sloooowwwww.

Does this information appear correct for the setup, or is there an apparent problem??

Comment: how configurable is your adsl router?  can you set it to use just dumb bridging mode and the run `pppoe` on your freebsd box?  that will be a lot simpler and a lot less problematic because then everthing is done on the freebsd box (and its external NIC, `em0` i think, has the public internet address).

Comment: @cas I don't think I can set up bridge mode on the adsl router. It's from the cable company and they have it pretty locked down.

Comment: if netstat is slow, it's almost certainly because it is trying to resolve hostnames for the IP addresses - and can't because the lan machine can't access the internet.  try `netstat -rn` to test.  it doesnt solve your problem, but i recommend running a local dns resolver (e.g. unbound) on your freebsd gw and configuring all the lan machines (perhaps via dhcp) to use it.

Comment: have you configured your freebsd box to do NAT?  or, better yet, configured the ADSL router to NAT **all** traffic from the LAN port, not just traffic with 192.168.0/24 src addresses?  See https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html for info about `ipfw` and NAT

Comment: @cas is it possible to manually configure dns for the lan machine to point to the gateway for dns resolution?  and no I  haven't configured NAT on the freebsd box and I don't know what you mean by having the adsl router NAT all traffic from the LAN port.

Comment: 1. manually configuring DNS on clients is certainly possible.  on unix/linux just edit `/etc/resolv.conf`.  if they are dhcp clients, they may overwrite that next time they refresh dhcp.  2. my suspicion is that your router is only NATting src IP addresses it recognises as coming from its LAN port.  i.e. 192.168.0/24.  and not NATTing packets with 10.x.x.x addresses.  You can configure your freebsd to NAT those 10.x.x.x addresses so the router thinks they're coming from the freebsd box itself (which is double-NATting and sub-optimal) or if you are lucky, you can configure the router to NAT all

Comment: @cas you were correct about the slow netstat. I installed and configured unbind as a validating caching recursive DNS server and set it up as authoritative for the lan. netstat is now lightning fast. At this point, I am left with a host that can ping the multi-homed machine, but not the router one step beyond it.

Comment: try running, in two separate terminals, tcpdump on both em0 and ue0.  while watching those, try to ping or traceroute from a lan client to the router or fetch a web page from the internet.  you should see the packet on both tcpdumps.  if you don't the problem is on the freebsd box - it's not forwarding pkts.  if you do, and the src ip has changed to 192.168.0.121 then your freebsd gw is NATting the pkts and the problem is on the adsl router.  if the packets are unchanged then you either need to configure NAT on freebsd or configure your router to NAT all packets as i mentioned before.

Comment: @cas your suggestion of watching tcpdump helped. The problem was that my router didn't have a route back to the box. I added a static route and a ping worked. I will now concentrate on how to set up nat to work on the FBSD box.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add a static route on your modem, to route all incoming traffic for 10.0.0.0/8 to 192.168.0.121.

I am rather assuming that NAT is being done in the modem here.

Answer (score 0):

This would be solution in `pf` firewall, in case NAT-ing is not done in modem.
However, NAT-ing can be done in `pppd` or `pppoe`, as you state you're using DSL.

Edit `/etc/pf.conf`:

```
external_iface="em0"  # your WAN facing interface
internal_iface="ue0" # your LAN facing interface

set skip on lo0 # skip filtering on loopback
nat on $external_iface from $internal_iface:network to any -> ( $external_iface:0)

block in on $external_iface

pass in quick on $internal_iface from $internal_iface:network to any keep state

pass out on $external_iface
```

Regarding DNS, you can setup a local_unbound on Frebsd box, set it to listen on `192.168.0.1`, then either push this configuration over `dhcpd` to your clients on LAN, or manually editing `/etc/resolv.conf` like:

```
echo 'nameserver 192.168.0.1' > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up NAT in your FreeBSD Router machine and need to NAT(With port translation) your 10.0.0.0/8 networks to 192.168.0.121/32 IP address. Otherwise your LAN machine can not access internet